# Push ViewController in NavigationController from side menu

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, menu, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm using a UINavigationController and I have a side menu in it. The problem is that when I want to push a UIViewController in the NavigationController from the side view it doesn't work. To do it, is use that code:

```
  [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];    

CDRecentChats* recentchats = [[CDRecentChats alloc]init];
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"conversation"];
[recentchats.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

As you can see, I first close de side menu and then call the NavigationController to push a new ViewController. Using that code, the only thing that happens is that the menu is closed, but the NavigationController doesnnt push any ViewController. what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`popToViewController` means to go back to one that has already been made part of the navigation controller's stack.  If you're trying to show a new one, use `pushViewController`.

Comment: Well I tried with pushViewController and it didn't work either.

Comment: OK...but that's a different problem.  There's at least a *chance* of making the push work.  :)

Comment: So do you know what can I do?

Comment: This line: `CDRecentChats* recentchats = [[CDRecentChats alloc]init];` creates a *new* `CDRecentChats`.  Being new, that means one that's not currently part of the view controller hierarchy so, even if it has a navigation controller, that controller isn't connected to the display.  If you're going to push something, you need to use a controller that's already handling the screen.

Comment: OK! So how can I access to CDRecentChats navigation controller from the menu class?

Comment: I can't answer that from the information in your question.  I don't know what object your above code is in or what reference that object may have to a "menu class".  How does the first instance of `CDRecentChats` get created and what other object holds a reference to it?

Comment: CDRecentClass is a ViewController that has a NavigationController (all created via Storyboard). It also has a side menu, from where I want to call the push viewcontroller of the CDRecentClass.